# Access to Hibernate mapped object inside transaction that creates it

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to have access to a `Hibernate` mapped object inside the transaction that creates it in order to make a clone of it.  There is a reason I want to make a clone of it via the `Hibernate Session` and not just using Object.clone() (long story...).

```
Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();

Gadget gadg = new Gadget(1 /* id */, "Gadget Name", "some label", 123);

session.save(gadg);

//this returns null
Gadget gadgClone = (Gadget)session.get(Gadget.class, gadg.getId());

//do something with the clone

tran.commit();
```

However, `gadgClone` is null.  Is it because it has not been committed yet?  Is there a way to make it accessible in the `session` before committing?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you clone the object before persisting it?
Why do you clone it after un-persisting it?...

Anyhow, have you tried to load the object from the cache? For performance reasons, you don't need to hit the database if your object resides in the cache.

```java
Gadget savedGadg = (Gadget) session.load(Gadget.class, gadg.getId());
```

Further you may need to initialize the object (and perhaps its fields), all before committing the transaction.

```java
Hibernate.initialize(savedGadg);
Hibernate.initialize(savedGadg.getCertainCollection());
```

Comment: i need to get a clone of it out of Hibernate.  there is a reason but it is too long and confusing to explain

Comment: It might be the case that Hibernate is failing at persisting your object. Any stack trace?...Monitoring HQL by setting `hibernate.show_sql` to `true` together with P6Spy can help you in nailing down what's going wrong as Hibernate persists your object :)